# Unable to get SVGR to load SVGs in my Next JS Project

Tags: svg, next.js

I'm a beginner web developer who is working on their first project with Next.js. I have hit an error with getting SVGs to load into my project as SVGs and could use some help finding the cause of it. Following online guides, I installed SVGR and updated my next.config.js file to this:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

I then imported my SVG file into my component as a component (following the SVGR guide I was using):

```
import Pizza from "/images/icons/pizza.svg";
```

Which causes this error to pop up:

```
./pages/index.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '/images/icons/pizza.svg'
  1 | import Image from "next/image";
> 2 | import Pizza from "/images/icons/pizza.svg";
```

I've spent the last day trying different fixes to similar issues I've found online but nothing seems to work. Can anyone spot why SVGR isn't working for me? Apologies if it's something super obvious. I appreciate any help or insight!

Comment: Your config looks good; it looks more like the import path is wrong. Try using relative paths from your file to import the image, e.g., `import Pizza from "../../images/icons/pizza.svg";`